# android игры на html5

Tags: android, html5

Привет, я хочу написать игру на html5. Я новичок ( как написать Main activity класс на js или с++? мне не нравится java поэтому не хочу на java.

Comment: Ищите доки к соответствующим технологиям. Ваш вопрос слишком общий и ответ на него превысит маскимальеую длину ответа. Ну и делать лучше таки на java. С остальным боли будет невероятно много на каждом шагу